# will gatg.js will be tracked in <body>

Tags: javascript, performance, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I tried including gtag.js on , works fine.

But I need to know whether google ads conversion will be tracked if I add gtag.js within  instead of  ?

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests inserting gtag in `head` so that it runs as soon as possible. However, it also works if you put it in the `body`, as well as the conversion tags.